# How do I check that a switch block is exhaustive in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have some code:

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

function getColorName(c: Color): string {
    switch(c) {
        case Color.Red:
            return 'red';
        case Color.Green:
            return 'green';
        // Forgot about Blue
    }

    throw new Error('Did not expect to be here');
}
```

I forgot to handle the `Color.Blue` case and I'd prefer to have gotten a compile error. How can I structure my code such that TypeScript flags this as an error?

Comment: Just wanted to inform people there's a two-line solution from @Carlos Gines if you scroll down far enough.

Comment: TypeScript's `noImplicitReturns` can help with this.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?  Just removing the `throw` is enough to get a compiler error for me https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSgJWAEwBosoBxZYUY7AIQTGGIF8MMAzMEAYwBcBLOCCgBzYD3hJkAOQCGEYAAouALliIUASlUBnHsj4hh6Etm0B3Pjy4ALJRuPZHjrjO3A1kgHR58yk04CKHjBkIQByCnwwgG5-Jxc3DxRPckoQPwDMqCCQ8OEKUBj-FhYgA and adding the missing Blue case makes it go away. This seems to hold across TS 3, TS 4, TS 5. Edit: I can see @Marcelo Lazaroni already posted this answer

Answer (score 239, accepted):

To do this, we'll use the `never` type (introduced in TypeScript 2.0) which represents values which "shouldn't" occur.

First step is to write a function:

```
function assertUnreachable(x: never): never {
    throw new Error("Didn't expect to get here");
}
```

Then use it in the `default` case (or equivalently, outside the switch):

```
function getColorName(c: Color): string {
    switch(c) {
        case Color.Red:
            return 'red';
        case Color.Green:
            return 'green';
    }
    return assertUnreachable(c);
}
```

At this point, you'll see an error:

```
return assertUnreachable(c);
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       Type "Color.Blue" is not assignable to type "never"
```

The error message indicates the cases you forgot to include in your exhaustive switch! If you left off multiple values, you'd see an error about e.g. `Color.Blue | Color.Yellow`.

Note that if you're using `strictNullChecks`, you'll need that `return` in front of the `assertUnreachable` call (otherwise it's optional).

You can get a little fancier if you like. If you're using a discriminated union, for example, it can be useful to recover the discriminant property in the assertion function for debugging purposes. It looks like this:

```
// Discriminated union using string literals
interface Dog {
    species: "canine";
    woof: string;
}
interface Cat {
    species: "feline";
    meow: string;
}
interface Fish {
    species: "pisces";
    meow: string;
}
type Pet = Dog | Cat | Fish;

// Externally-visible signature
function throwBadPet(p: never): never;
// Implementation signature
function throwBadPet(p: Pet) {
    throw new Error('Unknown pet kind: ' + p.species);
}

function meetPet(p: Pet) {
    switch(p.species) {
        case "canine":
            console.log("Who's a good boy? " + p.woof);
            break;
        case "feline":
            console.log("Pretty kitty: " + p.meow);
            break;
        default:
            // Argument of type 'Fish' not assignable to 'never'
            throwBadPet(p);
    }
}
```

This is a nice pattern because you get compile-time safety for making sure you handled all the cases you expected to. And if you do get a truly out-of-scope property (e.g. some JS caller made up a new `species`), you can throw a useful error message.

Comment: With `strictNullChecks` enabled, isn't it enough to define the function's return type as `string`, without needing an `assertUnreachable` function at all?

Comment: @dbandstra You can certainly do that, but as a generic pattern, the assertUnreachable is more dependable. It works even without `strictNullChecks` and also continues to work if there are conditions where you want to return undefined from outside the switch.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the enum is defined in an external d.ts file. At least I can't get it to work with the enum Office.MailboxEnums.RecipientType from Microsofts Office JS add-in API.

Comment: the above solution works for the basic example in the original description, however, I am not certain that it's a generally applicable pattern.  Swap out the color enum with `type InDiscriminant = { a: string } | { b: string }` and how can one proceed?  A simple switch no longer knows all of the stringy values, and there aren't common properties among member types of the union to discriminate over.  Is there an idiomatic solution for this case?

Comment: `noUnusedParameters` tsconfig set up will throw a "x is never used error" which you can fix by prefixing with underscore `function assertUnreachable(_x: never): never {
    throw new Error("Didn't expect to get here");
}`

Comment: Also be careful with the spread operator. Spreading will break these type unions and typescript will throw an error regardless if you have an exhaustive check or not.

Comment: If you use this with a string union type `type Pet = "Cat"|"Dog"|"Fish"` the error will only say that string is not assignable to never. Any way to get the name of the missing string in the error message?

Comment: For whatever reason mine will catch the missing case, but it doesn't provide a helpful error, it just complains about the import but doesn't explain which case is not being met. ie: `Type 'import("/color.enum").Color' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)` I ended up going with a mapping/dictionary lookup approach since it does seem to provide the missing case. I imagine this may vary from Typescript version.

Answer (score 114):

Building on top of Ryan's answer, I discovered [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions#switch) that there is no need for any extra function. We can do directly:

```
function getColorName(c: Color): string {
  switch (c) {
    case Color.Red:
      return "red";
    case Color.Green:
      return "green";
    // Forgot about Blue
    default:
      const exhaustiveCheck: never = c;
      throw new Error(`Unhandled color case: ${exhaustiveCheck}`);
  }
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSgJWAEwBosoBxZYUY7AIQTGAwF8MMAzMEAYwBcBLOCCgBzYD3hJkAOQCGEYAAouALliIUASlUBnHsj4hh6EtoDufHlwAWUJRuPZsXGduBrJAOjz5lJR1AoeMGQhACIKfFCAbj8oZ1d3FA9yShBff2xA4LDhClBo2IB6QqgAMRRhOB4oGQAjODBqugZY-GA2GTAEHnSMrkFdKGAADytO3T4AN2AYK2AuAGtVEGBp1ABeOJiMqB4rZDhTKBWjgFFkA+QFAAMAVRAxkHwEAjj1VHjgVQASNBGxsATaazeYLJjXDTbKAsJhAA) in TS Playground

Edit:
Included suggestion to avoid "unused variable" linter messages.

Comment: I prefer using variable too, instead of creating a function (though both might get stripped at bundle time). In any case, your linter may complain about an unused variable, and you'll have to add something like this above it: `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`

Comment: Or, you can use the variable in the error you throw, something like:
`throw new Error(\`Unexpected:  ${_exhaustiveCheck}\`);`

Comment: Nice idea.  You could also define an anonymous function: `default: ((x: never) => { throw new Error(c + " was unhandled."); })(c);`

Comment: I can confirm that @Nooodles solution satisfies SonarQube unused variables check. Thanks. Love how terse this is.

Comment: I addressed some related (I think these might be pretty frequent) errors from the code above like this: ```default: { const pleaseBeExhaustive: never = c; throw new Error(`Use all Color - ${pleaseBeExhaustive as string}`); }```

Comment: I can confirm that @Jonny's braces creating a scope around the default statement are necessary to prevent a `no-case-declarations` error from ESLint. Also, in PyCharm you need `// noinspection UnnecessaryLocalVariableJS` over the intermediate variable. Still, this is the best way to get a compile time error you can see.

Comment: In TS 4.9 this simplifies to `c satisfies never`. No assignment, and no unused variable.

Comment: 2 reasons to use a function. Run-time safety included. encapsulate the logic for easy re-use.

Answer (score 93):

You don't need to use `never` or add anything to the end of your `switch`.

If

- Your `switch` statement returns in each case
- You have the `strictNullChecks` typescript compilation flag turned on
- Your function has a specified return type
- The return type is not `undefined` or `void`

You will get an error if your `switch` statement is non-exhaustive as there will be a case where nothing is returned.

From your example, if you do

```
function getColorName(c: Color): string {
    switch(c) {
        case Color.Red:
            return 'red';
        case Color.Green:
            return 'green';
        // Forgot about Blue
    }
}
```

You will get the following compilation error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not
>   include `undefined`.

Comment: This solution require to explicitly specify all possible return values of a function. In other cases we can omit them and let compiler do type inference.

Comment: yes, the compiler will complain, but you should also consider, that you could still get a wrong value at runtime. In such a case, I prefer to throw a meaningful error-message (instead of implicitly returning undefined)

Comment: The idea is **not** to return `undefined`, but to create the missing branch of the case statement. This way you would not get an error at runtime and there is no need to throw anything.

Comment: @MarceloLazaroni your idea is good, but your code does not work that way At runtime there is no guarantee, that `c` is indeed a `Color` - since it is just JavaScript code the function can be called with anything: e.g. `c` could be a number, then your function would return `undefined`: see this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-39419170)

Comment: The code works exactly as described. If you will ignore the type and consider that `c` could be anything there is no reason to use TypeScript at all. If `c` could be null or undefined, the type should say that and the implementation would then take that into account.

Comment: @MarceloLazaroni I think you still don't get my point: typescript does NOT guard against runtime errors: i.e. when your function is called at runtime with anything other than a `Color` (for whatever reason), your function will return `undefined`. This is different to e.g. Java where the JVM would catch this type-error (at runtime) and throw some exception.

Comment: This solution works to trigger a typescript error, but the error is not always clear. I prefer to use a `default` case with an unused variable typed as `never` with a comment explaining `"hey bud, if you're getting an error here, you forgot to add a case"`. YMMV.

Comment: @TmTron but if the type of the method argument is ensured at compile time, how could an erroneous type ever be used at runtime? Assuming the source is pure typescript.

Comment: @S-K' when you get some external data: e.g. you request data from the server and then just cast it to your interface. Then the compiler will not complain, but when the server really sends any string instead of your expected enum, you get a runtime error. Or an old version of your app stored some data in local storage and a newer version reads this data - but the interface definition has changed.

Comment: @TmTron You're making the assumption that the enum is being mapped to data outside of the programs control. In the scenarios you mentioned, a fail fast approach with `throw new Error()` makes sense. But when the data is within the apps control, an exhaustive switch is great.

Comment: @S-K' this can even happen in your own program: e.g. the example with local storage and 2 different app versions, or someone uses a cast, etc. So adding a single throw can help you a lot when something unexpected happens..

Comment: This doesn't work if I have an interface (say, EventSymbolToInterfaceMap) where keys are symbols, and values are interfaces, and define the function like that: `getEventMessage<E extends keyof EventSymbolToInterfaceMap>(type: E) { switch (type) ... }`. I still have the "Function lacks ending return statement" error, but all four points from your answer are true for my code. Is it because the function is generic? `assertUnreachable` at the end still works, however, which is strange to me.

Comment: What IF my function is not supposed to return anything? It has a `void` return type, then?

Comment: @Nawaz then you don't meet one of the 4 requirements listed above for the use of this technique. You will need to do something else.

Comment: ah, right. I did not pay attention to the 4 requirements listed in this answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I was able to get this working with discriminated unions by asserting on the object itself instead of the property, like `assertUnreachable(myObj)`, where I'm switching on a property like `switch (myObj.color) {`

Comment: "when you get some external data: e.g. you request data from the server and then just cast it to your interface [...] this can even happen in your own program: e.g. the example with local storage [...]" -- Following up: the way to address this issue is to not blindly cast/blindly construct the enum from the raw value. The program must validate the raw value before constructing the enum from it. For example, the program could have a function like `colorFromRaw(rawValue: string) => Color` to construct the `Color` enum. The function throws if the input `rawValue` is invalid.

Comment: With the new Typescript version the `satisfies never` solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75217377/4617597 is the best one.

Answer (score 66):

`typescript-eslint` has *"exhaustiveness checking in switch with union type"* rule:
[@typescript-eslint/switch-exhaustiveness-check](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/9e0f6ddef7cd29f355f398c90f1986e51c4854f7/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/switch-exhaustiveness-check.md)

To configure this, enable the rule in `package.json` and enable the TypeScript parser. An example that works with React 17:

```json
"eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/switch-exhaustiveness-check": "warn"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    }
},
```

[image]

Comment: The ESLint `default` rule requires a default case anyway, which renders this rule useless since a default case makes everything exhaustive. Also the rule is noted as expensive. Note it doesn't work on enums (but union types are better anyway).

Comment: @Noumenon yes, if there is `default` rule then this rule is useless. It's as expensive as any eslint rule that requires reading types information.

Comment: Works on enums now @Noumenon.

Answer (score 43):

This is a lot easier in TypeScript 4.9 with the [`satisfies` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).

```js
enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

function getColorName(c: Color): string {
  switch(c) {
      case Color.Red:
          return 'Red';
      case Color.Green:
          return 'Green';
      case Color.Blue:
          return 'Blue';
      default:
          return c satisfies never;
  }
}
```

If your checks are exhaustive, `c` should always be of type `never`. We ‘assert’ this to the compiler with the `satisfies` keyword (in essence, telling it that `c` should be assignable to `never`, and to error otherwise). If, in the future, you add a new case to the enum, you will get a pure compile-time error.

Under the hood, the `default` branch will compile to:

```
default:
    return c;
```

This is a literal expression, which will only evaluate `c`. This shouldn’t have an effect on your code, but if `c` is, for example, a getter on a class, it will evaluate if the default branch ever runs and could have side effects (as it will in the currently accepted answer).

Comment: One minor comment here, it seems like typescript complains that when we do not add `return` keyword on the `default` case, other than that this is a perfect solution. Thanks

Answer (score 41):

### Solution

What I do is to define an error class:

```
export class UnreachableCaseError extends Error {
  constructor(val: never) {
    super(`Unreachable case: ${JSON.stringify(val)}`);
  }
}
```

and then throw this error in the default case:

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

function getColorName(c: Color): string {
  switch(c) {
      case Color.Red:
          return 'red, red wine';
      case Color.Green:
          return 'greenday';
      case Color.Blue:
          return "Im blue, daba dee daba";
      default:
          // Argument of type 'c' not assignable to 'never'
          throw new UnreachableCaseError(c);
  }
}
```

I think it's easier to read than the function approach recommended by Ryan, because the `throw` clause has the default syntax highlighting.

### Hint

The [ts-essentials](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials) library has a class [UnreachableCaseError](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#exhaustive-switch-cases) exactly for this use-case

### Runtime considerations

Note, that typescript code is transpiled to javascript: Thus all the typescript typechecks only work at compile time and **do not** exist at runtime: i.e. there is no guarantee that the variable `c` is really of type `Color`.
This is different from other languages: e.g. Java will also check the types at runtime and would throw a meaningful error if you tried to call the function with an argument of wrong type - but javascript doesn't.

This is the reason why it is important to throw a meaningful exception in the `default` case: [Stackblitz: throw meaningful error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/unreachable-case-error)

If you didn't do this, the function `getColorName()` would implicitly return `undefined` (when called with an unexpected argument): [Stackblitz: return any](https://stackblitz.com/edit/unreachable-case-return-any)

In the examples above, we directly used a variable of type `any` to illustrate the issue. This will hopefully not happen in real-world projects - but there are many other ways, that you could get a variable of a wrong type at runtime.
Here are some, that I have already seen (and I made some of these mistakes myself):

- using angular forms - these are not type-safe: all form field-values are of type `any`
  [ng-forms Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-types)
- implicit any is allowed
- an external value is used and not validated (e.g. http-response from the server is just cast to an interface)
- we read a value from local-storage that an older version of the app has written (these values have changed, so the new logic does not understand the old value)
- we use some 3rd party libs that are not type-safe (or simply have a bug)

So don't be lazy and write this additional default case - it can safe you a lot of headaches...

Comment: note, that you can currently not use `instanceof` checks for subclasses of `Error`: see [issue#13965](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965#issuecomment-278570200) which also mentions a workaround

Comment: I checked it and it works correctly now. TypeScript 3.5.1.

Comment: Ooooh, this is beautiful, and also almost exactly how I would write the code, if I was writing in plain JS.

Comment: How does the compiler find this?

Comment: @jocull not sure what you are asking for. Maybe you want to read about [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)?

Comment: I think that has the docs I was looking for - thanks :) [Exhaustiveness checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#exhaustiveness-checking)

Comment: Actually there's no need to put `val` into the `Error` message in `UnreachableCaseError`, if you are only after the TS ty-checking.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli Not sure what you mean. Throwing an exception in the default case is not related to the type of variable that is used in the switch statement - here is a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/unreachable-case-error-string?file=index.ts) that works with a string-enum

Comment: Note: this pattern works only if you return something in each case. If you are in a `forEach` loop, you can add `return;` to each case for example. Also, it did not work for a nested property in the switch for me, like `switch(foo.bar.zed)`, instead I did `const zed = foo.bar.zed` beforehand.

Comment: Actually after more try, it doesn't work very well on a nested prop, like `foo.bar.zed`. If you do `const zed = foo.bar.zed; switch(zed)...` you loose the automatic detection of `foo` type based on `zed` (think GeoJSON Geometry, that you can differentiate based on the type). But if you don't do this, `UnreachableError(foo.bar.zed)` won't work

Comment: Finally for nesting: you may need to do `UnreachableError(foo.bar)` in this case, even if you switch on `foob.bar.zed`.

Comment: *"Java will also check the types at runtime"* -- This is kind of a weird comparison, as type checks only happen in Java when explicitly downcasting a reference, or when using reflection. There is no runtime check when passing a reference to a function that accepts a compatible reference type, for example; it's assumed that the referent is of a compatible type. (If that's not the case then the type system broke and all bets are off.) The point is, there's usually not that much type checking happening at runtime in Java; it's still mostly compile-time.

Answer (score 8):

As a nice twist on Ryan's answer, you can replace `never` with an arbitrary string to make the error message more user friendly.

```
function assertUnreachable(x: 'error: Did you forget to handle this type?'): never {
    throw new Error("Didn't expect to get here");
}
```

Now, you get:

```
return assertUnreachable(c);
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       Type "Color.Blue" is not assignable to type "error: Did you forget to handle this type?"
```

This works because `never` can be assigned to anything, including an arbitrary string.

Comment: The clearer error message is nice but one small downside is that accidentally passing something with type 'any' won't trigger the error.

Answer (score 6):

Building on top of [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39419171/626911) and [Carlos'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009992/626911) answers, you can use an anonymous method to avoid having to create a separate named function:

```
function getColorName(c: Color): string {
  switch (c) {
    case Color.Red:
      return "red";
    case Color.Green:
      return "green";
    // Forgot about Blue
    default:
      ((x: never) => {
        throw new Error(`${x} was unhandled!`);
      })(c);
  }
}
```

If your switch is not exhaustive, you'll get a *compile* time error.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid Typescript or linter warnings:

```
    default:
        ((_: never): void => {})(c);
```

in context:

```
function getColorName(c: Color): string {
    switch(c) {
        case Color.Red:
            return 'red';
        case Color.Green:
            return 'green';
        default:
            ((_: never): void => {})(c);
    }
}
```

The difference between this solution and the others is

- there are no unreferenced named variables
- it does not throw an exception since Typescript will enforce that the code will `never` execute anyway

Comment: You are not wrong. However, I think throwing an Error is slightly safer here since it doesn't rely on the implementation details of TypeScript in the case of a problem (ie, if your runtime somehow manages to reach the never case despite your types, you'll at least get an error instead of undefined behavior). Since you can lie with typescript (eg by declaring something that is not proven), it's important to throw.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the mapped type for this:

```
enum Color {
  Red,
  Green,
  Blue,
}

type ColorMapper = {
  [Property in Color]: string
}

const colorMap: ColorMapper = {
  [Color.Red]: "red",
  [Color.Green]: "green",
  [Color.Blue]: "blue",
}

function getColorName(c: Color): string {
  return colorMap[c];
}
```

After you add a new value to `Color` you will need to meet `ColorMapper` requirements.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find a missing case is to activate TypeScript's check for [no implicit returns](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns). Just set `noImplicitReturns` to `true` in the `compilerOptions` section of your `tsconfig.json` file.

Afterwards you have to remove the `throw new Error` statement from your code, because it will prevent the TypeScript compiler from throwing an error (because your code is already throwing an error):

```
enum Color {
  Red,
  Green,
  Blue
}

function getColorName(c: Color): string {
  switch (c) {
    case Color.Red:
      return 'red';
    case Color.Green:
      return 'green';
  }
}
```

With the above code, you will have an implicit return (because if no case matches, the function will return `undefined`) and TypeScript's compiler will throw an error:

> TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

I've also made a video which demonstrates it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N_P-l5Kukk

In addition, I suggest to narrow down the return type of your function. It actually cannot return any `string` but only a defined set of strings:

```
function getColorName(c: Color): 'red' | 'blue'
```

Narrowing your return type can also help you to find missing cases as some IDEs (like VS Code & WebStorm) will show you when you have unused fields.

Answer (score 2):

In really simple cases when you just need to return some string by enum value it's easier (IMHO) to use some constant to store dictionary of results instead of using switch. For example:

```js
enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

function getColorName(c: Color): string {
  const colorNames: Record<Color, string> = {
    [Color.Red]: `I'm red`,
    [Color.Green]: `I'm green`,
    [Color.Blue]: `I'm blue, dabudi dabudai`,   
  }

  return colorNames[c] || ''
}
```

So here you will have to mention every enum value in constant, otherwise you get an error like, for example, if Blue is missing:

> TS2741: Property 'Blue' is missing in type '{ [Color.Red]: string; [Color.Green]: string;' but required in type 'Record'.

However it's often not the case and then it's really better to throw an error just like Ryan Cavanaugh proposed.

Also I was a bit upset when found that this won't work also:

```js
function getColorName(c: Color): string {
    switch(c) {
        case Color.Red:
            return 'red';
        case Color.Green:
            return 'green';
    }
    return '' as never // I had some hope that it rises a type error, but it doesn't :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function instead of using a `switch` statement.

```
export function exhaustSwitch<T extends string, TRet>(
  value: T,
  map: { [x in T]: () => TRet }
): TRet {
  return map[value]();
}
```

Example usage

```
type MyEnum = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const v = 'a' as MyEnum;

exhaustSwitch(v, {
  a: () => 1,
  b: () => 1,
  c: () => 1,
});
```

If you later add `d` to `MyEnum`, you will receive an error `Property 'd' is missing in type ...`

Comment: This only works if your enum values are strings since they need to be encoded as keys in the object parameter `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a useful variant dedicated to [tagged union types](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/tagged-union-types-in-typescript) which is a common use case of switch...case. This solution yields:

- type check at transpilation time
- **also** runtime check, because typescript doesn't guarantee us to be bug free + who knows where the data come from?

```
switch(payment.kind) {

        case 'cash':
            return reduceⵧprocessꘌcash(state, action)

        default:
            // @ts-expect-error TS2339
            throw new Error(`reduce_action() unrecognized type "${payment?.kind}!`)
    }
```

The 'never' detection comes for free from dereferencing the "never" base type. Since the error is expected if our code is correct, we flip it with `// @ts-expect-error` so that it fails if our code is incorrect. I'm mentioning the error ID in case it get supported soon.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers gave good solutions for returning functions. In case the function is not returning (void), we can add a return statement that will trigger a type-checking error when reached:

```
function visit(expr: Expr): void {
  switch (expr.__type) {
    case "Binary":
      break;
    case "Grouping":
      break;
    case "Literal":
      break;
    default:
      return expr // Missing "Unary", error: "Type 'Unary' is not assignable to type 'void'."
  }
}
```

Not the friendliest error message, but works.