# Narrowing string to string literal union

Tags: string, typescript, types, literals, unions

I want to narrow a string to a string literal union. In other words, I want to check if the string is one of the possible values of my literal union, so that this will work (if the operator `couldbe` existed).

```
type lit = "A" | "B" | "C";
let uni: lit;
let str = "B";
if(str couldbe lit){
    uni = str;
} else {
    doSomething(str);
}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

I tried using `if (str instanceof lit)`, but that doesn't seem to work. Using `keyof` to iterate over the string union doesn't work either, because the allowed values aren't keys per se.

One way would be to use `switch` with one case for each possible value, but that could lead to subtle errors if `lit`s allowed values change.

Comment: The type `lit` doesn't exist at runtime so you cannot use it like that. Maybe use an enum instead?

Comment: Regarding the switch statement comment, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419170/how-do-i-check-that-a-switch-block-is-exhaustive-in-typescript).

Comment: @NitzanTomer That is actually a very good idea, seems much cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 17):

If you hate switch cases, as I do:
since [TypeScript 3.4 – const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) it's also possible to produce union type from array of your strings ^_^

```
const lits = <const>["A", "B", "C"];
type Lit = typeof list[number]; // "A" | "B" | "C"

function isLit(str: string): str is Lit {
  return !!lits.find((lit) => str === lit);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [User-Defined Type Guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```
type lit = "A" | "B" | "C";
let uni: lit;
let str = "B";

function isLit(str: string): str is lit {
    return str == "A" || str == "B" || str == "C";
}
function doSomething(str: string) {

}

if (isLit(str)) {
    uni = str;
}
else {
    doSomething(str);
}
```

**ADD:**

To avoid duplicated edit, `class` can be used both for compile-time and run-time. Now all you have to do is to edit just one place.

```
class Lit {
    constructor(public A = 0, public B = 0, public C = 0) {}
}
type lit = keyof Lit;
let uni: lit;

function isLit(str: string): str is lit {
    let lit = new Lit();
    return (str in lit) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Hm, that's a little better than switch statements, but it still has the problem of possibly forgetting to update the type guard when `lit`s permitted values are changed.

Comment: I added another solution to my answer.

Comment: I like your second solution very much if one absolutely had to use literal unions. It seems like a better way would be to just switch to `enum`s, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is my take on the problem with the type guard and with `strictNullChecks` turned off (this is limitation on a project; if this option is `true` TS will require exhaustiveness on the `switch/case`).

Line `const _notLit: never = maybeLit;` guaranties that when you change `lit` type you need to update the `switch/case` also.

Downside of this solution is that it gets very verbose as the union type `lit` grows.

```
type lit = "A" | "B" | "C";

function isLit(str: string): str is lit {
  const maybeLit = str as lit;
  switch (maybeLit) {
    case "A":
    case "B":
    case "C":
      return true;
  }

  // assure exhaustiveness of the switch/case
  const _notLit: never = maybeLit;

  return false;
}
```

If possible this task is more suitable for `enum` or if you require a `type` and don't mind creating underlying enum for checking, you can create type guard something like this:

```
enum litEnum {
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
}
type lit = keyof typeof litEnum;

function isLit(str: string): str is lit {
  return litEnum[str] !== undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a [zod](https://zod.dev/?id=zod-enums) enum to do this:

```
import zod from 'zod'

const ColorMode = zod.enum(['light', 'dark', 'system'] as const)

let _mode = 'light' // type is string
let mode = ColorMode.parse(_mode) // type is "light" | "dark" | "system"

_mode = 'twilight'
mode = ColorMode.parse(_mode) // throws an error, not a valid value
```

You can also extract the type from the zod schema when needed:

```
type ColorMode = zod.infer<typeof ColorMode>
```

I find a validation library like this is the easiest and most robust way to parse, validate, and type-narrow variables/data when I would otherwise have to reach for manually-written and error-prone [type guards/predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it w/o any casting and "is":

```
let litArr = ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const;
type lit = typeof litArr[number];

let uni: lit;
let str = 'B';
let foundStr = litArr.find(item => item === str);

if (foundStr) {
    uni = foundStr;
} else {
    doSomething(str);
}
```