# How to indicate that path is unreachable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have some TypeScript code that looks essentially like this:

```
if( ... ) 
    result = $(document.createElement("div")) ;
} else if( ... ) {
    result = $(document.createElement("div")) ;
} else {
    assert.unreachable( "Unknown label in buildHTML.") ;
}
result.attr( "data-childNumber", childNumber.toString() ) ;
```

The return type of `assert.unreachable` is `never`.

There is an error on the last line:

> Variable 'result' is used before being assigned.

It seems to me that the `never` result from `assert.unreachable` should tell the compiler that there is no path out of the `else` part.

I know that I can suppress the error by adding `throw null;` at the end of the `else`, but this seems inelegant.

A similar problem comes up in the definition of `unreachable`. It looked like this

```
export function unreachable( message? : string ) : never {
    if( message===undefined ) message = "Unreachable code reached." ;
    else message = "Unreachable code reached: "+message ;
    raiseTheAlarm( message ) ;
}
```

where the result type of `raiseTheAlarm` is `never`.  In this case, I got an error:

> A function returning 'never' cannot have a reachable end point.

I fixed this by adding a `return` keyword before the call to  `raiseTheAlarm`.  This looks a bit odd.  (Of course, `throw null;` after the call would also have worked.)

Is there a better way to tell the compiler that a point in the code is not reachable?

Comment: The tsc compiler version is 2.3.4

Comment: The call to `assert.unreachable` *does* prevent subsequent code from executing, because the call to `assert.unreachable` function is never returned from.

Comment: Colour me educated about the `never` type. I totally missed that feature. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems to me that the never result from `assert.unreachable` should
>   tell the compiler that there is no path out of the else part.

It works the other way round. When compiler detects that some path is unreachable, it infers `never` type for variables referenced in that path, if it can. You can use it to enforce that your code handles all possible values for enum or union type, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419170/how-do-i-check-that-a-switch-block-is-exhaustive-in-typescript).

However, compiler does not use information that some path is unreachable when it checks that variable is not used before it's initialized. The solution is simple - you can assign `never` value to that variable in the unreachable path. As explained in the answer linked above, `never` was made assignable to any other type specifically for this purpose.

```
if( ... ) 
   result  = $(document.createElement("div")) ;
} else if( ... ) {
    result  = $(document.createElement("div")) ;
} else {
    result = assert.unreachable( "Unknown label in buildHTML.") ;
}
result.attr( "data-childNumber", childNumber.toString() ) ;
```

A problem with your `unreachable` function is fixed in the same way - it should have

```
return raiseTheAlarm( message ) ;
```

as the last statement.

Comment: Great answer. I have one quibble. You say "However, compiler does not use information that some path is unreachable when it checks that variable is not used before it's initialized." But the fact that adding a `throw null;` suppresses the error shows that the compiler does do that sometimes.

Comment: Adding `throw` or `return` tells the compiler explicitly that there is no path  that leaves `result` unassigned before use. One possible explanation is that [unreachable code analysis is entirely separate from analysis for detecting use before assignment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5207#issuecomment-147469302)  They probably should have an issue on github about that.

Answer (score 2):

Since [TypeScript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#satisfies) you can use the `satisfies never` statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three options

(a)

```
else {
    return assert.unreachable( "Unknown label in buildHTML.") ;
}
```

(b) (from @artem's answer)

```
else {
    result = assert.unreachable( "Unknown label in buildHTML.") ;
}
```

(c)

```
else {
    assert.unreachable( "Unknown label in buildHTML.") ;
    throw null ;
}
```

I went with option (a).