# Can TypeScript be used to determine if all types in union of string literals are used at least once?

Tags: typescript

I suspect the answer to this is "no" but if you don't ask, you don't get.

Imagine you've a union of string literals and you want to ensure that each entry in the string literal is used at least once.  Consider:

```
type MyEvents = 'User clicks button' | 'User opens menu' | 'User eats pizza'
```

Let's imagine we care a great deal that each of the above types is used.  If all of the above aren't used then it means we're not capturing the information that we need.  It represents an error state.

Wouldn't it be amazing if the compiler could tell us if one of the above wasn't used?  Kind of in the same way that `--noUnusedLocals` lets you know that you've a local variable you aren't using or `noUnusedParameters` tells you you've a parameter you're not using.

Is this possible?

### EDIT

To be a little more specific, I'm imagining this in the context of a whole program.

```
// file1.ts
// ...
trackThatThing('User clicks button')
// ...

// file2.ts
// ...
trackThatThing('User eats pizza')
// ...
```

Would result in the error: "'User opens menu' type not used" or similar.  Whereas:

```
// file1.ts
// ...
trackThatThing('User clicks button')
// ...

// file2.ts
// ...
trackThatThing('User opens menu')
// ...

// file3.ts
// ...
trackThatThing('User eats pizza')
// ...
```

would be fine

Comment: Do you mean in a `switch` or something (in which case see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39419170/3001761)? Or just in your codebase generally?

Comment: in the codebase generally - so if a type wasn't used in the context of a whole program it would be considered an error

Comment: @JohnReilly Nope, there is `noUnused*` flag to cover this

Comment: You want [pattern matching](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching) which is hopefully coming soon.  [F# examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#variable-patterns)

Comment: ... which has the potential to understand [exhaustive pattern matching](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/correctness-exhaustive-pattern-matching/) down the road.

Comment: I think this is broader than pattern matching Jason - or perhaps it's like pattern matching but where the scope is the whole program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of information isn't tracked by TypeScript during its checking phase.

Comment: I suspected not - thanks for confirming Ryan; I appreciate it!