# Typescript compiler not complaining about missing switch case

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, create-react-app, tsconfig

Consider the following code:

```
  enum MyEnum {
    Enum1,
    Enum2
  }

  function switchOverEnum(myEnum: MyEnum) {
    switch (myEnum) {
      case MyEnum.Enum1:
        console.log('it is an enum1');
        break;
      // I am missing the case MyEnum.Enum2 here,
      // but the TypeScript compiler does not complain
    }
  }
```

I am using this in a project created using `create-react-app`. My expectation is that TypeScript complains that the case `MyEnum.Enum2` is not handled, but it doesn't. How can I confiugre the TypeScript compiler to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
enum MyEnum {
  Enum1,
  Enum2
}

function switchOverEnum(myEnum: MyEnum) {
  switch (myEnum) {
    case MyEnum.Enum1:
      console.log('it is an enum1');
      break;
   
    case MyEnum.Enum2:
      console.log('it is an enum2');
      break;
   
    default:
      const exhaustiveCheck: never = myEnum;
      throw new Error(`Unhandled Enum case: ${exhaustiveCheck}`);
  }

}
```

Or with the anonymous function

```
  default:
      ((x: never) => {
        throw new Error(`${x} was unhandled!`);
      })(c);
```

see here [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAsgTwKKVgb2DGLoEYA0m2qATMAL7DABmEYAxgC4CWA9mDAM4Duzj9ACwDyANxAAnHFAAUUZKgBc8edACUMDFh59BMWSqjrNWGPQCGnEMqkA6KbgVETp9p1YAbEDfesA5tIByPhhmThgzDnA8ANUAbicTACNxEDMAa3iTBPNLa1Q7UkdnLHpXDy8ffyDGELCImCioEhjM4uTUjKcEgBMQajMId0Yi4tKwThqQAA8BAYnmMQBhARB6NKUwEDFxGABeGDkpVudGAXFWbhhNy6Rxc-FpAAMAVTBZsG7PbuJoUwsQJQAEjQ01mEHmSxWa3IjziREoFGAQA)

For more ways see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39419170/9161478)