# Do exhaustion checks in switch-cases via `never` have any runtime use-case?

Tags: typescript

Currently looking at the exhaustion checks for e.g. `switch-case` in TypeScript (see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html). There is an example of a `switch` on `shape.kind` property, that looks like this:

```
type Shape = Circle | Square;
 
function getArea(shape: Shape) {
  switch (shape.kind) {
    case "circle":
      return Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2;
    case "square":
      return shape.sideLength ** 2;
    default:
      const _exhaustiveCheck: never = shape;
      return _exhaustiveCheck;
  }
}
```

Right now, my understanding is, that this `default` check solely exists for compile-time checking, *i.e.*  the `tsc` will see this `default`-case and if there is a possibility of `never = something-else` occuring, e.g. "triangle" if `Shape` is rather defined like this: `type Shape = Circle | Square | Triangle;`, like in the error-example, then this will throw an error during compilation.

Does it mean, these exhaustion checks are intended to be only relevant at compile time? Are there scenarios, where such an exhaustion check `default` block could be executed on runtime?

Comment: That exhaustiveness check is only intended to help at compile time, although it's completely unnecessary in current versions of TS (see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mqxadN)).  There *might* be times when you want a runtime check of something in case you turn out to be wrong about your TS types, but that's essentially an independent concern from this code (and such places should be refactored to the boundaries of your code base so that you only make such checks in one place and not throughout).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: It does adress the question, yes, but I think your answer is at odds with the answer by TmTron. Their `any`-example resolves to a call to the `default`-block, making it code accessible on runtime, rather being a pure compile-time check. Unless I misunderstood your response.

Comment: It's an independent concern.  If some non-TS code calls your TS code at runtime, it could do anything it likes.  If that's an issue, you should make sure that you only expose some well-defined places for such outside code to call your code, and do your extra runtime checking there.  Presumably one could also write TS code that loosens type checking on purpose like `getArea(null as any)` but anything that breaks as a result of that should be fixed by the offending caller and not the function implementation.  None of this has much to do with the point of that exhaustiveness check, though.

Comment: Even when you only have typescript-code there are countless ways how to get an unexpected value as parameter to your function. So the "independent concern" is actually what kind of error-handling you prefer. Just ignore it and hope for the best, or invest 2 lines of code to throw a meaningful runtime-exception.

Comment: The fact that anything at all can happen at runtime is not really relevant. Q: "Does this mean that these exhaustion checks are intended to be only relevant at compile time" A:  **yes**.  Q: "Are there scenarios, where such an exhaustion check default block could be executed on runtime?" A: **yes, but that's not why that code was written**. To defend against all possible violations of the types you would need to be a lot more cautious than that exhaustiveness check.  For example, `getArea(null as any)` will explode at runtime *even with the check*.

Comment: It is really truly an independent concern from that exhaustiveness check.  It was not written to catch any runtime problem (what is even the point? to return the input whatever it happened to be instead of the intended `number`? If it wrote `return 0` or something I could see it).  Yes, you can write more thorough checks to defend against possible type violations, *but this code is not doing that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the block could be called at runtime with anything: e.g. `getArea("abc" as any)`.
In that case your function will return the string `"abc"`.
[Full Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGWQGtQATALmQCIENsJqBuQ5KOM4AVwGcqQuAWwBG0FgF9C%20UJFiIUAZQCOXOFDytSISjR4q1jFkR7AyEADIQQAczAALfkNFQJUsAE8ADortxvyAF40ehxkAB9kZVV1I3wYLhAEMGAAexBkawgwAEF1OAAKHl9vKgViiABKZAJjAHdgMAQ7ZELygDotMiqaomQEOB4UWhDGClZetiyuKHSAWTh7NoAFAElkACpkIr8INvZOXg3NgCYjXv7B3X11ajGJonUwafTt7zaTM0sbeyPkU-HkGZ4FwsGA7vcEGkeGBkAB9CAAD18vGSADcIKg7BAEMR%20BB0VBAltymcJo9nnDEcjocB0ZjscQzpJJPhISBocgDHAiZkcnl8gByODCBACzk8TkgdwVFhsngpHBtLApayCrkCgA0nLyFSAA)

Thus, I always prefer to throw an Exception in the default block: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913382/1041641

Comment: To clarify, how would the function return `"abc"`? In order to achieve that, `never = shape` needs to be assigned, but according to the documentation `never` can only be assigned `never`. Does `any` get narrowed to `never` in this scenario?

Comment: "never" and "any" are just typescript types - at runtime (in javascript) there are no types, so everything just becomes a variable: check the `.JS` tab in the Playground example to see the actual javascript.

Comment: I meant, `tsc` should recognize the possibility of `any` being assigned to `never` in the example above, which is not allowed according to the TS documentation. That's why I was wondering, if the `tsc` infers the `never` type via narrowing and thus permits this assignment without throwing an error at compile time (regardless of the actual JS code being executed on runtime). Your example is obviously working as you describe, I am just trying to understand, what the `tsc` does under the hood.

Comment: When we use `any` for the type of the parameter that we pass to the `getArea` function, we actually deactivate the type checks for the parameter - so we basically convince typescript that our `abc` string is a valid shape.
The `getArea` function has no notion of this: i.e. the parameter is a `Shape` (and never `any`)

Comment: Apologies for being slow, but I still have trouble understanding. Assuming no info of type `any` makes it into `getArea`, it then means, that `tsc` cannot infer type `never` from `any` due to narrowing. Therefore type is `Shape`. But then how does the assignment `never = shape` work in the `default` case? Again, according to the documentation in the link I posted, nothing other than `never` can be assigned to `never`, so `never = Shape` is not a valid assignment. Does it mean, `tsc` infers, that `Shape` must be `never` in the `default` case, because it realizes the case cannot be reached?

Comment: @Koenigsberg right. since typescript knows all possible types of shape (and thus the kinds), it can see that you have already handled all valid cases, so the variable `shape` in the default branch is of type `never`. You can verify this when you hover the mouse over the `shape` variable in the default block of the Playground example: the pop-up window shows that `shape` is indeed of type `never`. When you hover over `shape` in the `square` case, the type is `Square`.

Answer (score 1):

That exhaustiveness check is indeed only intended to help at compile time, to be sure that you have explicitly checked each separate case.  You only need something like this if you aren't comfortable letting the code fall through.  It isn't necessary if you are `return`ing from every `case` and don't `return` after it, since the compiler will warn you anyway that not all code paths return a value if you make a mistake:

```
function getArea(shape: Shape) { // okay
    switch (shape.kind) {
        case "circle":
            return Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2;
        case "square":
            return shape.sideLength ** 2;
    }
} 

function getAreaBad(shape: Shape) { // error! Not all code paths return a value.
    switch (shape.kind) {
        case "circle":
            return Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2;
        //case "square":
          //  return shape.sideLength ** 2;
    }
}
```

---

It is of course technically possible for the code in that `default` block to run at runtime, but only if the TypeScript types are violated in some way such as non-TS code calling your code, or TS code using unsafe [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the unsound [`any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any)... but it's an independent concern.

Such handling of potential violations of expectations could be important for certain use cases, but that exhaustiveness check wouldn't be how anyone should write it.

First, in the case of unexpected input, it just returns the input where every other code path returns a `number`. Meaning that TypeScript will let you treat it as a `number` and you've just moved your explosion to later in your code:

```
try {
    const x = getAreaWithDefault("abc" as any);
    x.toFixed(); // looks fine to TypeScript
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e) //  x.toFixed is not a function
}
```

Perhaps if it were to `return 0` or some other number, there would be a reasonable argument that the block was performing some useful runtime sanitizing.

Next, if you were truly concerned about random inputs, you'd have to expect that `shape` itself might not let you index into it to read `kind`.  So you can pass in `null` or `undefined` and the code will explode inside your function before you've reached the `default` block:

```
try {
    const y = getAreaWithDefault(null as any);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); //  shape is null
}
```

So while it's definitely true that some use cases might necessitate more runtime checks than TypeScript thinks are needed, that has very little to do with the exhaustiveness check from the handbook, whose intent was only to ask the compiler to complain if you failed to explicitly handle a case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGSOQGtQATALmQCIENsIaBuQ4qOc4AVwGdqQ3ALYAjaKwC++fKEixEKAMoBHbnCh42RMiCq1eq9U1bFkvYOQgAZCCADmYABYDhYqJOlgAngAcljuD9kAF40BhxkAB9kFTUNVnwYbhAEMGAAexBkOwgwAEENOAAKXgC-akUyiABKZFxkAHoG5HSSOC8tMwB3YDAER2QSqoA6HXJaglNTBDheFDpwpkpOqfZc7igsgFk4J2GABQBJZAAqMxGOLj5Ts4AmE1XkGbn9Qw0aZcepjTANrNLAhBhuZLDZ7E4bsh7p0pFJEslUhksjl8oUAEKcIaAipVCaNZrQKDpKAAQmQADl0mBkHAsFgnulLMgfLtHLxkD8-jTkAA3WncIGdXg9PoDLF+UYUCYrYjPeb0TA4D4y1aczbIHZ7I6nc6A4aXHjsk53B6rJpy15xJYq-FENX-EYg6y2BwDY1Q03IWHSeEpNKZbK5AoQOAAdV6jgAIhB4NwsGBxRAcYDpaZhb1+oMARKxqnHhaForrV9TPaNayDscztmgQbru7oV8CwYrcqS2tfuqa8CLM7wW6TTbLLH4592wyQLxqQB9CAADwCfDSPIgqEcEAQJAEEBXUBCur8nq+ZdnC7gS+AK7XG5Inu9+DAUC8dU6CEyU+Qc-3KODYYj0ZHBMaDgEQEBoGl2TgEAvGqT052GMB0gAMWAOcIHIIpYPwCQnl2TMihqF9pnfdIcGGLB0jsAjaiaT8EOQ1D0OQYB2RAKluSSP0kWwzwnyI2V32pZ9Qh-QpwycADz3jIpBDpCCaWgrCcJmUVBkIyYBMnUigQoqiamYW0a2Y1i4ywbCgA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailled answer. :) A follow-up question on your first examples `getArea` and `getAreaBad`: You are mentioning, the exhaustiveness check is no longer needed in modern TS, because `tsc` recognizes, when a possible case has no return value (if I understand you correctly). But if I expand those examples by a `default` case **without** the `never` assignment, then all paths return a value, yet I may have explicit cases which I did not handle.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the exhaustiveness check to recognize scenarios, where explicit case handling is missing, rather than to ensure all execution paths return a valid value? Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by, "not necessary in current versions of TypeScript". In any case, thank you for your explanations so far

Comment: If you use `default` without `never` then you *have* handled all cases, just not explicitly.  Yeah, if you want to be sure you haven't let a case fall through to `default` then you need some kind of "`never` checker".  I'll edit my answer not to focus on whether it's necessary or not