# Exhaustive match on class static methods in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have a class that defines a number of instances of itself as its own static methods:

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(
    public readonly angles: number,
    public readonly color: string
  ){}

  static Triangle = new Shape(3, "red");
  static Rectangle = new Shape(4, "blue");
  static Circle = new Shape(0, "green");
}
```

This class is used as a rich enum, as in the below example of a shape catchphrase generator - a function that takes an argument of type Shape and returns a different catchphrase for each shape type.

```js
function shapeCatchPhrase(shape: Shape): string {
  switch (shape) {
    case Shape.Triangle:
      return "Three is a magic number";
    case Shape.Rectangle:
      return `Are you a ${shape.color} square?`;
    case Shape.Circle:
      return `Oh! Look at your ${shape.angles} angles!`;
  }
  throw new Error("No such shape!");
}
```

Notice the `throw` after the switch statement. It will throw an error if the shape passed was not one of the three above.

Is there a way to instruct Typescript to match the three static shapes exhaustively and raise a compile-time error if one of them is not handled?

I have tried converting them to a union type like so:

```js
type ShapeType = Shape.Circle | Shape.Rectangle | Shape.Triangle;
```

Unfortunately, the above approach does not work and Typescript returns a syntax error.

Comment: Your `static` stuff are not really methods or types, they are just three values of type `Shape`. TS does have `enum`s though, and you can create a function that maps each variant to its properties (angles and color).

Comment: Btw, if I'm being pedantic, a circle is more like a shape with `Infinity` angles...

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to have an enum somewhere:

```
export enum ShapeType {
    Triangle,
    Rectangle,
    Circle
}

export class Shape {
    constructor(
      public readonly type: ShapeType,
      public readonly angles: number,
      public readonly color: string
    ){}
  
    static readonly Triangle = new Shape(ShapeType.Triangle, 3, "red");
    static readonly Rectangle = new Shape(ShapeType.Rectangle,4, "blue");
    static readonly Circle = new Shape(ShapeType.Circle,0, "green");
  }
```

...

```
assertUnreachable(x: never): never {
  throw new Error("Didn't expect to get here");
}
    
shapeCatchPhrase(shape: Shape): string {
  switch (shape.type) {
    case ShapeType.Triangle: return "Three is a magic number";
    case ShapeType.Rectangle: return `Are you a ${shape.color} square?`;
  }
  return this.assertUnreachable(shape.type); // compiler will complain here
}
```

Credits to: [How do I check that a switch block is exhaustive in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419170/how-do-i-check-that-a-switch-block-is-exhaustive-in-typescript)