# How to apply an ESLint rule only to switch statements with union or enum types?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have created a custom ESLint rule that ensures all switch statements have a default case returning a call to [assertUnreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419170/how-do-i-check-that-a-switch-block-is-exhaustive-in-typescript) with an argument that matches the variable in the switch. This is great, however it currently applies to all switch statements, regardless of the type used.

I am facing difficulty in implementing the logic to selectively apply the rule only to switch statements with union or enum types in their discriminants (i.e., the rule should only apply when switching variables that are union or enum types).

Here's the code of the custom ESLint rule so far:

```js
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    module.exports = {
      rules: {'exhaustive-switch-on-unions-and-enums': {
        create(context) {
          function getTypeName(node) {
            if (node.type === 'TSTypeReference') {
              return node.typeName.name;
            } else if (node.type === 'TSUnionType') {
              return node.types.map(getTypeName).join(' | ');
            } else if (node.type === 'TSEnumDeclaration') {
              return 'enum';
            }
            return null;
          }
      
          function hasDefaultCaseWithAssertUnreachable(node) {
            if (!node.cases || node.cases.length === 0) {
              return false;
            }
      
            const defaultCase = node.cases.find((caseClause) => caseClause.test === null);
            if (!defaultCase) {
              return false;
            }
      
            const { consequent } = defaultCase;
            if (
              consequent.length === 1 &&
              consequent[0].type === 'ReturnStatement' &&
              consequent[0].argument &&
              consequent[0].argument.type === 'CallExpression' &&
              consequent[0].argument.callee.name === 'assertUnreachable'
            ) {
              const switchType = context.getTypeChecker().getTypeAtLocation(context.getNodeFromContext(node.discriminant));
              const switchTypeName = getTypeName(switchType);
              const argumentType = consequent[0].argument.arguments[0];
              if (argumentType.type === 'Identifier' && argumentType.name === switchTypeName) {
                return true;
              }
            }
      
            return false;
          }
      
          return {
            SwitchStatement(node) {
              if (!hasDefaultCaseWithAssertUnreachable(node)) {
                context.report({
                  node,
                  message: 'Switch statement must have a default case returning assertUnreachable with the correct type.',
                });
              }
            },
          };
        },
      }}}
```

I have typescript-eslint installed which I think should allow me to type-check in ESLint.